# Quickblox Performance

Tags: objective-c, quickblox

I just wish to know if login in user to chat quickblox is typically slow. Its taking 7-10 seconds to login user to quickblox. Im located in Asia Pacific region and im just wondering if it has something to do with it. Or maybe because im in free tier.

Comment: Free tier, Europe, same problem, Session creation and signIn is taking too much time, maybe there is a way to keep session last longer?

Comment: I agree. Hope someone from quickblox provide an official statement on this. :)

Answer (score 1):

To speed up the process of signing in, please consider an Enterprise instance solution which would be located in geographically closest region to your user base.

You can find our Enterprise solutions here: https://quickblox.com/enterprise/